# Do I need to do some "cleanup" if an installation is terminated due to disconnection?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, php7, cleanup

I was trying to install php7.3 to my ubuntu 16.04 machine. The SSH connection got dropped while the installation was running. I've been trying to search whether I need to do a "cleanup" before I go ahead and re-install it, but all I get from google is something else like "how to terminate a process".

Any hints or direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How were you installing your software? Via a package manager or from source?  But in general, you can simple repeat the install and see if you experience errors/warnings.

Comment: @HBrujin is correct, normally any package having enough logic to detect pre-deployed files or binaries, So try to redeploy same package and see if it is giving you exception or warning. Most of the things package will handle his own it just ask for your acceptance in **yes/no** or **y/n**